# Does pressing back destroy the top two Activities in Standard mode?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have 3 activities A,B and C. A is the main activity, B is a child of A and C is a child of B. 
I am using the launch mode "standard" for every activity. Now I have started activity C so the activity stack is [A,B,C]. If I now press the back button, C is destroyed like one would expect but instead of just returning to the B activity, which is now on top of the stack, this activity is also destroyed and a new instance of B is created (not using savedInstanceState). Is this normal behaviour?

If I change the launchmode of B to singleTop I just return to B like expected.

Edit: I have not set additional values in the manifest file except the child-parent relationships explained above. I am using the support library version 7.22.1.1, min sdk version 15 and target sdk version 21. I'm running the app on an emulated Nexus 5.

Comment: The behaviour you have described does not seem to be usual for android.
In order to aid community help you please provide some additional info:
1) do you use any other attributes in the activity description in the manifest file?
2) where did you catch this issue (is it device or emulator, an api version)?

Comment: I added the requested information. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your initialization code is within onStart() or onResume() rather than onCreate()?  I would suggest adding log statements into all onXXX() methods so you can trace exactly what is being called.  Maybe this will provide insight so you can shift your code around and prevent this behavior.

Comment: I already did that. Activity B's onDestroy isCalled and directly after onCreate is called.